# git pull --rebase didn't pull new files from origin

Tags: git, rebase

I pulled a package and worked for a while now. All my changes are done worked fine and before pushing it to remote, I did a `git pull --rebase` as I pulled the code long ago and others might have done some changes. There were some conflicts which I could resolve manually but there were some new files added to remote repository and pull --rebase doesn't get those new files. As a result my package cannot build now, as some of the code changes made by rebase uses those new files. Where did I do it wrong? Fix please?

Answer (score 0):

Check your current git status to see if the rebase isn't still in progress.

When you resolve some conflicts during a rebase, you need to add them to the index, and then type `git rebase --continue`. If you don't, Git won't replay all your commits, and the resulting working tree might lack some files.

Also check that those new files are indeed part of the upstream branch on top of which your current rebase applies: a `pull --rebase` would by default replay your commits on top of `origin/yourCurrentBranch`: are new those files part of that `origin/yourCurrentBranch`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand git, but I had the same issue and for me a

```
git pull origin master
```

helped.